# When data is added to the firestore, I want to listen with onSnapshot so that the data can be called automatically, but I don't know how to use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I want to listen for the value of message in the data structure in the attached image

I get an error with this code

```js
secondDb.collection("chats")
  .doc(dockey)
  .onSnapshot(function (doc) {
    doc.docChanges().forEach(function (change) {
      if (change.type === "added") {
        console.log(doc.data().messages[0]);
      } else if (change.type === "modified") {
        // 
      } else if (change.type === "removed") {
        // 
      }
    })
  });
```

error code
doc.docChanges is not a function

The data structure is as follows:
[image: Data Structure]

Comment: You might want to check if .onSnapshots is called on the Firestore.CollectionReference, not on DocumentReference

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data over the collection you want to retrieve

```
var unsubscribe = firestore().collection('chats').onSnapshot(snapshot =>{
  snapshot .docChanges().map((change) => {
   if (change.type === "added") {
    console.log(doc.data().messages[0]);
   } else if (change.type === "modified") {
     // 
   } else if (change.type === "removed") {
     // 
   }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data structure, I would say that you probably don't want to call `.onSnapshot` on your entire collection.

Your initial code was fine. But, since you called `.onSnapshot` on a DocumentReference, you got a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot). Instead of `.docChanges` you would just do `doc.data().messages`.

You should also check out the documentation on [Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#realtime_updates) for realtime updates.

If you're trying to make a realtime messaging app, you might consider using Firebase Cloud Messaging instead of `onSnapshot`.
You could load all the messages for a conversation from Firestore when a user opens the app, and receive any new ones using FCM as long as the user is connected to the internet.

Comment: You gave me a new perspective　Thanks so much！

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck with your project.
頑張って！ ^^